# Why $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am reading a text book and I am struggling with a step. 
We have a curve $f(x,y)=0$ and it says that everywhere on this curve it is true that

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

How do I know that this is true? Is there a graphical intuition behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**intuition**
The vector
$$
\mathbf n = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) ,
$$
the gradient of $f$, the direction in which $f$ increases most rapidly, is:

> normal to the curve $f(x,y) = 0$.

On the other hand, the vector
$$
\mathbf t = \left(\frac{dx}{dx},\frac{dy}{dx}\right)
$$
is

> tangent to the curve $f(x,y)=0$,

where we parameterize it by $x$.

Finally, the normal and the tangent are orthogonal to each other, so their dot product is zero:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dy}{dx}=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\partial f/\partial x$ is how fast $f$ is changing with respect to $x$ when $y$ is fixed. If $dx$ is an infinitely small change in $x,$ then $(\partial f/\partial x)\,dx$ is the corresponding change in $f.$ Similarly for $(\partial f/\partial y)\,dy.$ If both $x$ and $y$ are changing, then those two components are added to get $df.$